# Titanium Studio 3.2.1 requires Android 5.0

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, android-sdk-tools

I've tried to install Android SDK and configure it with Titanium Studio for 5 days. I used every method described in stackoverflow/appcelerator and nothing. Below you've got screen shots from Titanium Studio and SDK Manager. Have anyone any idea how to fix this?

I'm using Windows 8.1.

**Titanium Studio info:**

[image: Titanium studio info]

**Android SDK info:**

[image: Android SDK info]

Comment: Since Android 5.0 hasn't been released, and neither screenshot shows anything about Android 5.0,I have idea what you are asking for.

Comment: I know what are you thinking about but at the screenshot you can see that i unchecked obsolete button. I've installed SDK Platform and Google APIs from Android 2.0(API 5)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue after updating the **Titanium SDK**. It worked properly after I did the following

1. Updating the Titanium Studio to the latest
2. Updating the Android SDK to the latest. Include Google APIs also.
3. Included all the SDK from Android 2.1 (API level 7, Since Titanium requires minimum API Level 8; See the figure)
4. Restarted my Titanium Studio after updating the SDKs

[image]

Hope it helped you

Comment: Ok, i'll check this solution and i'll let you know. It's 50 packages to install so it can take a while...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Titanium Studio still says that i haven't install Android SDK. `An Android SDK is missing. Titanium requires Android platform 5.0`. Have you install anything from API lover than 8?

Comment: I have installed them too. This is [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/bkvXBhv.jpg) from my Android SDK. Titanium still requires API 5.0 :c

Comment: @MrShemek: Open the dashboard and click the 'Install or Update Android SDK' button. It will display a dialog, select the android and update it.

Comment: still the same message, after i've updated all android SDK i've got dialog: [screen](http://i.imgur.com/glbyiRz.png)

Comment: Have you restarted the studio after updating the sdk?

Comment: Yes, this didn't help.